# Create a Linux user with different profiles by command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, redhat

I was wondering if it was possible to override the SKEL property when adding a user in Linux.

Man page gives me everything to change dynamically any property (SHELL, HOME, ...) but not SKEL.

What I want to do is find a way to assign one profile or another to the users I'm creating.

For instance, I need to create a user with a `.profile` in which `VAR=value1`, and another user with a `.profile` in which `VAR=value2`. My idea was to create different SKEL, one for those who need `VAR=value1`, another for those needing `VAR=value2`, and simply execute `adduser ... -D -magic_option /SKEL/for/value1` or `adduser ... -D -magic_option /SKEL/for/value2`. But `-magic_option` doesn't seem to exist.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, just use the `-k` option in `useradd`:

> **-k, --skel SKEL_DIR**
>
> The skeleton directory, which contains files and directories to be
>   copied in the user's home directory, when the home directory is
>   created by useradd.
>
> This option is only valid if the -m (or --create-home) option is
>   specified.
>
> If this option is not set, the skeleton directory is defined by the
>   SKEL variable in /etc/default/useradd or, by default, /etc/skel.
>
> If possible, the ACLs and extended attributes are copied.

So you can create your `/my/skel_for_users` and `/my/other_skel_for_users` and use either of them whenever creating one.

Comment: I don't know in what I was thinking about when I read the man page, but as a matter of fact, -k is explained... Well, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!